# how to recover deleted file on Android programmatically

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-sdcard, android

We are developing Android application (Android UI and C application through JNI). We are developing for our storage device.

I like to know whether any API is there (OR any method) to recover deleted files programmatically.

There are tools to recover deleted files. I want to know how they are able to achieve it.

Please provide your ideas.

Comment: I don't think there's an API call for it. You may be able to do it, but it probably depends on which file system is used. I know of *at least* ext4, yaffs, rfs, and fat32 being used, depending on what device, and whether it's internal, external, or SD card.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It is external SD card and file system mounted is VFAT.

Comment: @user1587643 - unless the device is rooted, lack of permission to access the raw storage volume means the best approach would be to remove the card and perform the recover with a PC.  If it is rooted, then the internals of a linux-based recovery solution could be ported.  Technically, if the device has USB host mode & APIs, then moving the card to a USB reader could allow the recovery to be done without needing root, though at the cost of having to implement the USB mass storage protocol in your app.